# AWS CodeDeploy behaviour during scaleup event

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Code Deploy with autoscaling and i need to know what will happen if EC2 scale-in and scale-out event occur during deployment.Please chech below mentioned question.

1) How will CodeDeploy detect newly created instance due to scale out event during deployment process going on.

2) What will happen to code deploy process currently running in instance which get terminated by auto scaling due ti scali-in event. Will the code deploy deployment process fail or it will continue with newly created instance in auto scaling group.

3) What will happen if autoscaling group in assosiated with more than one deployment group.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find an answer to such detailed questions is either:

1. **Test it yourself**. All these scenarios should be quite easy to reproduce and you will know first hand how it behaves.
2. **Ask AWS Support**, they are usually quite knowledgeable. However even they may have to spend some time figuring out the exact behaviour.

If I were you I would *test it*.

Comment: Thanks MLu, mine is not paid developer support plan.Any way will try to test it and will update the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

We had failed deployments when original instances were terminated at BLUE-GREEN-DEPLOYMENT.  As a workaround, we suspend all scaling for the time of the deployment.

```
aws autoscaling suspend-processes --auto-scaling-group-name $ORIGINAL_ASG
```